# Am I using HttpGet and HttpPost wrong? ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, http-get

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int ProductID, string Name, decimal Price, string Photo, int Likes, string Description, Enums.ProductCategory.Category Category) 
{
    ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel
    {
        ProductID = ProductID,
        Name = Name,
        Price = Price,
        Photo = Photo,
        Likes = Likes,
        Description = Description,
        Category = Category
    };
    return View(productModel); 
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int ProductID)
{
    if(UserController.userSessionID != 0)
    {
        user.DeleteProduct(ProductID);
        return RedirectToAction("ViewSellerProducts", "Product");
    }
    return View();
}
```

But I read HttpGet is only supossed to get data and do nothing else, which `[HttpGet]DeleteProduct()` isn't doing. The fact is, if I would change `DeleteProduct()` to `[HttpPost]` the ID would be 0, so how would I get the ID in the view?

When the products are set on page:
[image]

When I'm on the page that shows all the details and I have to click on delete:

[image]

Comment: 1. It's strange that you annotate the first `DeleteProduct` action method with `HttpPost` and the 2nd `DeleteProduct` method with `HttpGet`. IMO, the first one should be `HttpGet` and the 2nd one should be `HttpPost`.  2. Also, please replace your screenshot images with codes (text). Otherwise, it's likely somebody will vote down for that.

Comment: @itminus I know it makes more sense, but when I change the second delete to `HttpPost` I don't get a ProductID, I just get 0.

Comment: also why are you posting data in a delete or get other than the id, aka  
        `Name = Name,
        Price = Price,
        Photo = Photo,
        Likes = Likes,
        Description = Description,
        Category = Category` is probably not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `input` with the product id to pass it as `HttpPost`

```html
<form asp-action="DeleteProduct">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductID" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
    ...
</form>
```